# Output 403 Forbidden when trying to upload an image from iOS App

Tags: php, ios, xcode, xcode6

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to upload an image using POST method in my first iOS App and I'm trying and trying but something is wrong or maybe something is missing I'm not sure about that but I'm getting the message "***403 Forbidden***" and also a long text:

```
<!--
   - Unfortunately, Microsoft has added a clever new
   - "feature" to Internet Explorer. If the text of
   - an error's message is "too small", specifically
   - less than 512 bytes, Internet Explorer returns
   - its own error message. You can turn that off,
   - but it's pretty tricky to find switch called
   - "smart error messages". That means, of course,
   - that short error messages are censored by default.
   - IIS always returns error messages that are long
   - enough to make Internet Explorer happy. The
   - workaround is pretty simple: pad the error
   - message with a big comment like this to push it
   - over the five hundred and twelve bytes minimum.
   - Of course, that's exactly what you're reading
   - right now.
-->
```

And I'm not sure what I have to do now because I just followed a tutorial in order to upload an image to my FTP.

I'm going to post my code from xcode:

```
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 90);
            NSString *urlString = @"http://website.com/register.php";

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

            NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
            NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
            [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

            NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"hello.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [request setHTTPBody:body];

            NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
            NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(returnString);
```

And that's my PHP file:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './imagenes/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://website.com/imagenes/{$file}";
}
?>
```

**What I have to do to make this work?**
I think I'm very close but it's not working at the moment...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got any solutions???